Using gpgsm to verify signature of document
I need to  verify that a document is indeed encrypted by a particular key. I am able to encrypt and sign a file (separate commands) using the following (Running on Windows)
> gpgsm -er mysignature --batch --yes --output readme.txt.encrypted readme.txt
gpgsm: encrypted data created

> gpgsm -s --batch --yes --output readme.txt.signed readme.txt
gpgsm: signature created

I am able to decrypt the document using:
gpgsm --decrypt readme.txt.encrypted

And verify signature using
gpgsm --verify readme.txt.signed

However, how do I ensure the document is encrypted by a particular key?
Thanks in advance.

I am beginning to think that gpgsm is not a good solution. I am exploring using entirely openssl, with following workflow. Main issue is PKI is not suitable for encrypting large documents, so encryption is using aes256 but the key is encrypted using PKI:

generate random key using openssl
sign original doc with my private key
encrypt file with generated random key using aes256
encrypt key with pkeyutl using recipient public key
send encrypted key, encrypted file and signature to recipient

recipient side

decrypt key using recipient private key
decrypt file using decrypted key
verify document against sender public key and signature


You mean PKC = public-key cryptography; PKI = public-key infrastructure never encrypts anything. Both S/MIME and PGP schemes, implemented by gpgsm and gpg respectively, use exactly the hybrid encryption you describe (encrypt the data by a symmetric cipher with a nonce key and encrypt or otherwise exchange the nonce key with PKC) and both do identify the encryption key which your openssl method does not (although openssl also supports S/MIME and CMS, which do). And in any case it is not about a programming or development issue, thus offtopic.
